# find_element is not printing the actual text

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.espn.go.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print driver.find_element_by_class_name("timestamp")
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

My result is

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7b9bac74-fc4e-436f-ba2b-f723bc1e4abd", element="{e91179d6-990c-463f-b56b-a2a38fabecdb}")>
```

instead of the time stamp: ex: 3h

**It does this for everything, I get that weird session and element code instead of the actual text. Even when I change to another element or try a different website**. Also, even when I use `print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='timestamp']")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see printed is the *`WebElement` object string representation*. [`WebElement`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) instance is returned when you call any `find_element_by_*` method in Python-Selenium.

Instead, you meant to get the `text`:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("timestamp").text
```